# Files will not update after setting up Cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, cloudflare

I setup cloud flare for and tried it out, it messed up my entire site by caching pages and sending the same page over and over (I use ajax and call the page over and over). I took it off and switched back to my old nameservers. Now when I edit a file on my server and save it and refresh the page it stays the same? I think it's just waiting for the nameservers to update back to the old ones, but can someone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making changes to the static content on your site? If so, you should be going to [Development Mode](http://www.cloudflare.com/wiki/Development_Mode) before doing so to bypass the cache. CloudFlare doesn't cache Ajax...so I think something else is going on here.

If the AJAX call is being messed with for some reason, you can also set a rule to [bypass CloudlFlare's cache using PageRules](http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-fine-grained-feature-co).

Please contact us if problems continue.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess about DNS is probably right but you'll need to give us the domain name if you want us to confirm it.

You can confirm it yourself with:

```
dig yourdomain.com
```

And then:

```
dig -x the IP address from above
```

If the IP address belongs to CloudFlare, then that's your answer.